# How to Run a Python Program that Takes Command-Line arguments from within a Java Program

Tags: java

I understand that to run another Java program from inside a Java program you use something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/**A command goes here*/")
```

But how would I run a Python program that takes command-line arguments?
More specifically, my Java program takes a file as a command-line argument. I then pass this file in to a Python program, which then produces another file in the same directory. I will be  able to access this new file.

Can I simply call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /**directory_of_the_python_program arguments_for_program*/");
```

I'm also a bit confused about what goes inside "exec(...)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capturing the standard output, so you can use `print` in python to output to this stream:

```
try {  
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python yourProgram.py thearg1 thearg2");  
    p.waitFor();
    InputStream stderr = proc.getOutputStream();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Python says: " + line);
    }
    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

In your python program, to output to the Java program, use print like:

```
print 'Hi!'
```

To see what the Java program sent you, you can use `sys.argv`:

```
print 'The Java program sent me: ', str(sys.argv)
```

Note: I am not a python expert, and have not done much with it. Please tell me if I get some syntax wrong.